# roll mean and sd not including actual value using TTR and data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I need the mean and sd from specific window that does not consider actual value. The runMean and runSD from package TTR will be perfect but them consider the actual value. For instance, using TTR and data.table:

```
x<-c(4, 10, 7, 3, 9, 8)
dt<- as.data.table(x)
dt[, ':=' (mean = runMean(x,3), sd = runSD(x,3))]

    x     mean       sd
1:  4       NA       NA
2: 10       NA       NA
3:  7 7.000000 3.000000
4:  3 6.666667 3.511885
5:  9 6.333333 3.055050
6:  8 6.666667 3.214550
```

but the expected result should be

```
    x     mean       sd
1:  4       NA       NA
2: 10       NA       NA
3:  7       NA       NA
4:  3 7.000000 3.000000
5:  9 6.666667 3.511885
6:  8 6.333333 3.055050
```

I think that it will be a way to do it using data.table but I don't know how to do that. Any help will be much appreciated, I am learning data.table.

Comment: I get `runMean(x, 3)#
[1]       NA       NA 7.000000 6.666667 6.333333 6.666667`  So, it is not clear why you think that it is data.table doing differently

Comment: In the first case, 7 is the mean of (4,10,7) it includes the actual value x=7. In the second case 7 is the mean of the same values (4,10,7) but the actual value of x is 3.

Comment: See `?shift` from the data.table package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shift function, as pointed in comments by @Frank, the output, which you want can be obtained using :

```
library(data.table)
library(TTR)
x<-c(4, 10, 7, 3, 9, 8)
dt<- as.data.table(x)
dt[, ':=' (mean = shift(runMean(x,3), 1), sd = shift(runSD(x,3), 1))]
```

This will give :

```
dt
    x     mean       sd
1:  4       NA       NA
2: 10       NA       NA
3:  7       NA       NA
4:  3 7.000000 3.000000
5:  9 6.666667 3.511885
6:  8 6.333333 3.055050
```